# Add comment popover not visible on mobile

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

[image: screenshot of issue]
When clicking 'Add comment' a popover appears about reputation if it applies to you (e.g. not logged in or not enough rep).

This popover is not visible on mobile unless you scroll right (see screenshot), meaning when you tap 'Add comment', nothing appears to happen.

Unsure if this affects a number of SE sites, or just codegolf.